# not valid json file

Tags: json, json-schema-validator, onos

I have this json file, but i can't figure out why the validator says that is invalid.
Can you help me with it?

Thanks in advance!

```
 {   
   "apps": {
     "org.onosproject.xran": {
       "xran": {
         "active_cells": [
           {
             "plmn_id": "000001",
             "eci": "00000010",
             "ip_addr": "1.1.1.2"
           },
           {
             "plmn_id": "000002",
             "eci": "00000020",
             "ip_addr": "1.1.1.3"
           }
         ],
         "l2_meas_report_interval_ms": 5000,
         "rx_signal_meas_report_interval_ms": 7000,
         "xranc_cellconfigrequest_interval_seconds": 10,
         "xranc_bind_ip": "1.1.1.1",
         "xranc_port": 7891,
         "admission_success": true,
         "bearer_success": true,
         "no_meas_link_removal_ms": 1000000,
         "idle_ue_removal_ms": 1,
         "nb_response_timeout_ms": 10000
       }
     }  
   } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different validator? It's valid JSON on the top 5 Google SERP validators I checked

Comment: After some tries, it was a python version problem, thank you very much!